# May I use console input property value in psql function body

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am executing SQL scripts like:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres --set=user_app=myservice_app --set=user_app_pswd=asdf1234 -f ../sql/create-app-user.sql
```

where the `create-app-user.sql` script is:

```
DO
$body$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
      WHERE usename = ':user_app')
  THEN

    CREATE USER ":user_app" WITH PASSWORD ':user_app_pswd';
  END IF;
END
$body$;
```

Everything works fine except the `CREATE USER ":user_app"` part, since the double quotes interpret the string directly. I can't use single quotes like `CREATE USER ':user_app'` because it throws `syntax error at or near "':user_app'"`. Using no quotes at all results in the same error.

Escaping doesn't help either. So, I'm wondering, how to use a property value with double quotes? Or any other solution with variables maybe?

Comment: Did you try --set=user_app='myservice_app' and leave off quotes in sql file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE USER ' || quote_ident(:user_app)
           || ' WITH PASSWORD ' || quote_literal(:user_app_pswd);
```